# Connecting swings with sql

Tags: java, sql, database, swing

I want to learn sql connectivity with swings(java) can any one suggest a good resource available for my purpose.

Comment: Tell us how much do you know so we can suggest a good resource. The question is too broad

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look up how to use MVC with Swing, where Swing is your View, and your controller handles getting the data into and out of the database via JDBC or an ORM intermediary like Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to connect MySQL with Java. To do that you will need MySQL java connector

[Link 1](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/)
[Link 2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JDBC-Drivers/Downloadmysqlconnectorjava513rcbinjar.htm)
[A complete tutorial, But long :)](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381)

Please add more info. So we can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

This link has the exact solution to your question.

[A Simple login app in Java Swings & Mysql](http://praveenmax.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/simple-login-application-in-java-using-swings/) 
A swing application for login validation.
You need to download the "MySql Connector for Java"(aka JConnector) from the site [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)/
After downloading,place the mysql_connector.jar file in your project folder.Better use some IDE such Eclipse or other .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **NetBeans IDE**. Among the java templates, there is an application generating a simple swing interface accessing a database. It implements the good practices with **JPA**.

Answer (score 0):

The best link i could give you is

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B36ZqeHukmpeZWZLRUhxb1FJclU. This ppt helped me to connect swings with sql.

I have a written a code, that connects the sql with swings. There is also signup detail function which tells you how to use the sql with swings.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Database {
    static String JDBC_DRIVER,DB_URL;
    String USER,PASS;
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;

    public Database()
    {
           // JDBC driver name and database URL
        JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        USER = "root";
        PASS = "anshtiger";
        conn = null;
        stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        ResultSet rs1=null;
        try{
              //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

              //STEP 3: Open a connection
              System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            //STEP 4: Execute a query
              System.out.println("Creating statement...");
              stmt = conn.createStatement();
              String sq;
              sq = "create  database if not exists AIRLINE";
                stmt.execute(sq);
                System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                String sql="use AIRLINE";
                stmt.execute(sql);


           }catch(SQLException se1){                      //Handle errors for JDBC
              se1.printStackTrace();
           }catch(Exception e){                            //Handle errors for Class.forName
              e.printStackTrace();
              }




    }

   public void signupdetail(String userid, String pass2, String question, String answer, String fname, String lname,
            String gender, String string, String martial, String email,
            String mobileno, String nationality, String address, String city, String state, String country, String pincode){
   {
   try{

        String sq1 = "create table if not exists customerdetail(userid varchar(20) unique, primary key(userid),password varchar(20),question varchar(100),answer varchar(30),fname varchar(20),lname varchar(20),gender varchar(10) ,dob varchar(20),martialstatus varchar(10),emailid varchar(30),mobileno varchar(10),nationality varchar(15),address varchar(50),city varchar(15),state varchar(20),country varchar(20),pincode varchar(8))";
        stmt.execute(sq1);
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");

        String sql2="insert into customerdetail values('"+userid+"','"+pass2+"','"+question+"','"+answer+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+gender+"','"+string+"','"+martial+"','"+email+"','"+mobileno+"','"+nationality+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+state+"','"+country+"','"+pincode+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);

      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se1){                      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se1.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){                            //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();}
     finally{ //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se3){
         se3.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally 
     }
   }
}
```